# Rails CarrierWave not uploading different sizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I tired to upload different sizes of images to AWS S3, but there is nothing shown up. Here is my config:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog
  # storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  def fog_public
    true
  end


  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :large do
    process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]
  end

  version :medium, from_version: :large do
    process resize_to_limit: [500, 500]
  end

  version :thumb, from_version: :medium do
    process resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
  end

  version :square do
    process resize_to_fill: [500,500]
  end

end
```

Here are my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploaders :attachments, AttachmentUploader

    belongs_to :user
    has_one :product_category

    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :product_category_id, :presence => true
    validates :payment_type, :presence => true
end
```

And my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

    def layout_by_resource
    "product"
  end

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @categories = ProductCategory.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.payment_type = params[:product][:payment_type].to_i
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        # format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'product was successfully created.' }
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        # format.html { render :new }
        format.html { redirect_to products_path }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :product_category_id, {attachments: []})
    end

end
```

When I comment out the create different version in `attactment_uploader.rb`, I can upload one file to S3. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, only large image can be resized in small but small image can not be resized.

Try this one.

```
 class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
   # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

   # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
   storage :fog
  # storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  def fog_public
    true
  end


  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:

  version :standard do
    process :resize_to_fill => [344, 258, :north]
  end

  version :large do
    process :resize_to_fit => [800,800]
  end

  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fill => [400,400]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :scale => [100, 100]
  end

  version :square do
    process resize_to_fill: [500,500]
  end

end
```